# Why bother quantize() a floating-point number given that we have round() function?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

I read in a Python book saying that in financial world, sometimes it'd be better using quantize() and decimal module to round off floating-point numbers. An example is given in the book as below,

```
from decimal import Decimal
price = Decimal('19.99')
tax = Decimal('0.06')
total = price + (price * tax) 
penny = Decimal('0.01')
total.quantize(penny)
```

But why not

```
round(19.99+19.99*0.06,2)
```

When does quantize() outperform round() in terms of numerical accuracy? Anyone can provide an example?

Comment: [Always.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the main reason for using Decimal (and quantize) is speed: it's accuracy. From the docs:

> Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect 1.1 + 2.2 to display as 3.3000000000000003 as it does with binary floating point.

If you are dealing with big numbers and you require the result to be correct up to 1 cent, then the accuracy (with floating point arithmetics) may be an issue.